# Javascript call web-based Javascript file

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a .js file that needs to initialize Parse. I can't put it into an html file because that's how my program works. To initialize Parse, you usually call the .js script from an html document. How am I supposed to initialize Parse without html?

Comment: If you don't have HTML what is your environment? Are you running Node, v8, something else?

Comment: I actually have this javascript running inside of a python file i'm using for data scraping, and I want to upload the scraped data to parse. However, Parse doesn't have a python api, so I'm using PyExecJS to run javascript within the python.

Comment: Why not just use their REST-API then? https://www.parse.com/docs/rest